# How do I stop an animation for a while between segments in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I have a moving point. It has two segments, and I need to stop the animation between them for a while. How do I reach it? Is there some way to reach this?

```
private void TrainAnim()
{
    Path myPath = new Path();
    myPath.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
    myPath.StrokeThickness = 1;

    PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
    PathFigure pathFigure = new PathFigure();
    pathFigure.StartPoint = new Point(10, 20);
    pathFigure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(new Point(100, 20), true));

    pathFigure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(new Point(400, 20), true));

    pathGeometry.Figures.Add(pathFigure);

    myPath.Data = pathGeometry;

    Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse
    {
        Fill = Brushes.Purple,
        Height = 20,
        Width = 20,
        Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0)
    };

    DoubleAnimationUsingPath anim = new DoubleAnimationUsingPath
    {
        PathGeometry = pathGeometry,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    };

    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard
    {

    };

    Storyboard.SetTargetName(anim, ellipse.Name);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty));
    storyboard.Children.Add(anim);

    canvasAnim.Children.Add(ellipse);
    canvasAnim.Children.Add(myPath);

    ellipse.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, anim);
}
```

Is there some way to do it?
canvasAnim is Canvas on MainWindow.

Comment: Run two animations with the two path segments, where the second one has an appropriate BeginTime.